# Filter Power BI Dashbord by URL Parameter

Tags: powerbi, powerbuilder, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

I need to filter data in a public dashboard publish-to-web Power BI like a example.

[Spain](https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiZTA5N2VkYWQtYmNiMS00YWFmLWEwZWQtOGY4MmExNTlmZjllIiwidCI6ImMyOGQyZTEyLTA5ODgtNGFjZi1iZGJhLTExOTU4MmU4ZDA4ZCIsImMiOjl9&Country=Spain)

[France](https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiZTA5N2VkYWQtYmNiMS00YWFmLWEwZWQtOGY4MmExNTlmZjllIiwidCI6ImMyOGQyZTEyLTA5ODgtNGFjZi1iZGJhLTExOTU4MmU4ZDA4ZCIsImMiOjl9&Country=France)

I can filter in a non-public url dashboard but I cant filter by Parameter in publish-to-web Power BI.

It is mean, I can build a Dashboard with data from a table with

| Column A | Column B |

| Field A0 | Field B0 |

| Field A1 | Field B1 |

Then, I publish-to-web with Power BI service, this service generate a url like
https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiN2EzOTM0Y2YtODVlZS00NGFjLTk5MTEtOGM4ZGY2NGZhYTNkIiwidCI6IjhmYmFhNWJmLTJlY2MtNGRjOC1iNTZiLThmOTJlMzA3ZjA3NiIsImMiOjR9
It is just a example

I need to filter by Field A0 or Field A1 the data by url parameter like
https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiN2EzOTM0Y2YtODVlZS00NGFjLTk5MTEtOGM4ZGY2NGZhYTNkIiwidCI6IjhmYmFhNWJmLTJlY2MtNGRjOC1iNTZiLThmOTJlMzA3ZjA3NiIsImMiOjR9&Column A=Field A0

and the dashboard just show data related with Field A0 and hide all data from other fields.

pd: sorry my english is very bad

Answer (score 1):

URL filters are [not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-url-filters#considerations-and-troubleshooting) with [Publish to web](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-publish-to-web) reports:

> URL filters are supported in some embedding scenarios and not in others.
>
> - Embedding a report in a secure portal or website is supported.
> - URL filters are supported in Power BI Embedded. See Power BI Embedded advanced URL filtering capabilities for details.
> - **Query string filtering doesn't work with Publish to web or Export to PDF.**
> - Embed with report web part in SharePoint Online doesn't support URL filters.
> - Teams doesn't allow specifying a URL.

If you want to use `Publish to web`, you must add the filtering in the report itself - either by [report/page/visual level filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/power-bi-report-add-filter), or a [slicer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-slicers), or to [filter the data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/power-query-quickstart-using-power-bi). The other option is to [embed the report in a web application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers) and use [the full filtering capabilities of the API](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Filters).

Comment: I know that URL filters are not supported with Publish to web reports, but in this example
https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiZTA5N2VkYWQtYmNiMS00YWFmLWEwZWQtOGY4MmExNTlmZjllIiwidCI6ImMyOGQyZTEyLTA5ODgtNGFjZi1iZGJhLTExOTU4MmU4ZDA4ZCIsImMiOjl9&Country=Spain

https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiZTA5N2VkYWQtYmNiMS00YWFmLWEwZWQtOGY4MmExNTlmZjllIiwidCI6ImMyOGQyZTEyLTA5ODgtNGFjZi1iZGJhLTExOTU4MmU4ZDA4ZCIsImMiOjl9&Country=France

use URL Filter

Comment: This is quite weird indeed. In the last 30 minutes I'm digging into this. For now the only explanation that I can think of is that some of the custom visuals (there are custom visuals used in this report) is looking for the `Country` key in the url and filters the data based on its value. This isn't the normal filtering behavior of Power BI. For example if you write an invalid filter (change `Country` to something else) it will not filter the report and show all the data, which doesn't happen in this case.

Comment: But I could 2 Dashboard, one with all data and one with filter data, now I must make a dashboard per parameter