# How can I use url query parameter to set the value of a 'Parameters' in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi

In PowerBI, I have a managed parameter which is a list of text.
`abc`, `def`, `ghi`.

And that parameter is being use to call a custom function in powerbi i.e. `MyCustomFunction(@Name)`

My question is how can I change the value of the parameter from the url when I load the report (after i published it to PowerBI service)?

i.e. I would like to

```
https://mypowerbi url?filter Name eq 'abc'  
`MyCustomFunction('abc')' will be called.

https://mypowerbi url?filter Name eq 'def'  
`MyCustomFunction('def')' will be called.
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter Power BI Dashbord by URL Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63744421/filter-power-bi-dashbord-by-url-parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is how can I change the value of the parameter from the url when I load the report (after i published it to PowerBI service)?

You can't. In Power BI reports, the URL query parameters can be used to **filter** the report. See [Filter a report using query string parameters in the URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-url-filters)

Parameters can be set from the URL in **paginated reports** only (legacy from SSRS). See [Pass a report parameter within a URL for a Power BI paginated report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports/parameters/pass-report-parameter-url).

For Power BI reports published to Power BI Service, the parameter values can be changed from the dataset's settings. See [Edit parameter settings in the Power BI service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-parameters). Keep in mind that this affects all users, who see the report, and it is not something that can affect your viewing session only. Changing parameter values of imported datasets usually will take a dataset refresh for the changes to take effect.

Parameters of published reports can also be updated using the Power BI's REST API - see [Update Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/update-parameters) and [Update Parameters In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/update-parameters-in-group).

Comment: Thanks for your detail answers.  After I publish my PBI report to PBI service, how can I change the name of the report and data set? I am thinking about publish my PBI report twice to PBI service, and then they have different parameter settings values in BPI service.  

But I can only find way to rename the dataset, not the report itself.

Comment: You can't. The easiest way is to create a copy of your report on your computer with the new name and publish both the original and the copy.